# To what degree is 戈 used in common Mandarin?

Tags: characters, radicals

I understand that the phonetic part of 我 (wo3) is pronounced 戈 (ge1). It seems also that it means (or used to mean) "Dagger"/"Sword", however the only references I can find to this character says that that is an old, defunct usage.

So, to what degree is this character used in common Mandarin? Is it just thought of as a radical, or does it have some other usage in speech?

Comment: It's part of the word for the Gobi desert 戈壁沙漠, very common.

Comment: see e.g. bkrs, esp  #10697 (frequency) https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E6%88%88

Comment: 戈壁 in戈壁沙漠 is a transliteration of Gobi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It seems also that it means (or used to mean) "Dagger"/"Sword", however the only references I can find to this character says that that is an old, defunct usage.*

[戈](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/747/) as a noun, simply mean 'dagger-axe or halberd'
The reason that it is an old, defunct usage, is no one are using it in modern warfare. Therefore the term 戈 as a weapon had disappeared from common vocabulary

> *So, to what degree is this character used in common Mandarin? Is it just thought of as a radical, or does it have some other usage in speech?*

戈 beside being a common radical, is also part of some 'warfare' related compound words and idiom.

Example:

干戈  = warfare

同室操戈 = infighting; fight between family members, partners or allies (
*Two athletes from the same nation fighting for the Gold medal can be described as 同室操戈*)

> 止弋為武
>
> 1. toes + dagger-axe = advance with weapon = 武 (force);
> 2. 止(stop)+ dagger-axe = stopping war = force
>
> *#1 is the more likely origin of 武*

戈 is often used as a transliteration word, for example: 戈壁 in 戈壁沙漠 is a transliteration of Gobi; 探戈 in 探戈舞 is the transliteration of Tango

Answer (score 0):

in oracle script, 我 (u+6211) is:

[image]

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=我](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%91)

then, 戈 (u+6208) is:

[image]

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=戈](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%88)

in which, the right half of 我 is 戈.

further, in cantonese (sydney lay scheme),

我 (u+6211) is ngoh5, [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/ngo5.Mp3)

戈 (u+6208) is gwoh1, [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/gwo1.Mp3)

both share the same final **oh**. we might say that "戈" is the phonetic component of the character of "我"

most of the usages of "戈" are weapons / arms related, like "干戈".

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000069665

and yes, it's one of the 214 radicals.

have fun :)